# Why does `ping` not timeout in Linux?

Tags: linux, ping

I just figured out, that `ping` on a Linux platform (Ubuntu 13.10) does not timeout as described. I tried

```
ping -w 2 unreachable.com
```

and

```
ping -W 2 unreachable.com
```

but in neither case there was a timeout after 2 seconds. How can I use `ping` with a definite timeout? Is that possible at all? I want the command to stop after 2 seconds, regardless of any connection status.

Comment: works  fine on my 13.04 install here. waits 2 seconds and then bails.

Comment: ping -w 2 <ip> works on one box and on an my FC14 box it is ping -t 2 <ip>

Comment: I'm also experiencing a problem like this on NixOS.

Answer (score 15):

`ping -c 5 -W 2` will send out 5 pings, waiting 2 seconds max for each of them (a total max of 10 seconds).

`ping -w 5` will send out pings, but will stop after 5 seconds.

You have to be careful with name resolution: if you use a name instead of an IP address, the resolution of the name does not count into these timeouts & waits (pinging and time measurements start only after the name resolution has finished). If you use DNS, you can set DNS timeouts in `/etc/resolv.conf` - see its man page.

Answer (score 3):

Are you misinterpreting the flag? If I understand correctly:

The -W flag will specify how long to wait for a reply. By setting -W 2, according to the man page:

> Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absense of any responses, otherwise ping waits for two RTTs

So running it like you have and waiting for 2 seconds doesn't actually let you know if it has given up waiting for the response or not.