# timeout not working in Perl script for function for some domains I'm pinging

Tags: perl, ping

I can't figure out whats going on here. My example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Net::Ping;
use Time::Out qw(timeout) ;

my $p = Net::Ping->new();

my $domain = lc("play9112.com");

print qq|Doing $domain \n|;

my $ping_result = timeout 3 => sub {
    return $p->ping($domain,5);
} ;

unless ($ping_result) {
    print qq|Don't seem to be able to grab $domain! \n|;
} else {
    print qq|needs to delete...\n|; # delete is done below!
}
```

The above code works on about 99% of cases. But there are some domains it just locks up on, and doesn't "timeout"! As a test, instead of `Time::Out`, I tested it with just a normal `eval {}` block:

```
my $TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 5;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
    alarm($TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);

    $p->ping($domain,5);

    # do stuff that might timeout.
    alarm(0);
};
if ($@) {
    # handle timeout condition.
}
```

This seems to have the same problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction? There must be a quirk, or something I'm missing!

**UPDATE:** I just tried it with -d and get:

```
perl -d test-ping.cgi

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.51
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(test-ping.cgi:8):                my $p = Net::Ping->new();
  DB<1>

  DB<1>   n
main::(test-ping.cgi:11):               my $domain = lc("play9112.com");
  DB<1> n
main::(test-ping.cgi:13):               print qq|Doing $domain \n|;
  DB<1> n
Doing play9112.com
main::(test-ping.cgi:27):               my $TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 5;
  DB<1>
main::(test-ping.cgi:28):               eval {
  DB<1>
main::(test-ping.cgi:29):                   local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
  DB<1>
main::(test-ping.cgi:30):                   alarm($TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
  DB<1>
main::(test-ping.cgi:32):                   $p->ping($domain,5);
  DB<1>
```

It hangs after that last part. So its something in Net::Ping thats doing it :/

Comment: I suppose the internal timeout of the ping function would use SIGALRM, just like the external one you provide by Time::Out. And the two signal handlers create a race condition in such a way that you might end up with neither of them being active.

Comment: @HellmarBecker thanks. But it seems to work with most others? So far I've come across maybe 20-30 domains. It locks up my script , and I'm having go through manually and remove them from the DB - far from ideal :(

Comment: @HellmarBecker I just run it with the `-d` flag. Seems to be Net::Ping thats hanging it up, but its a bit odd I don't see more debug from inside Net::Ping, as to *what* is hanging?

Comment: [Net::Ping](https://perldoc.perl.org/Net::Ping) comes with its own timeout implementation. Maybe you should use that.

Comment: @ceving thanks - but that has the same issue :( `my $domain = lc("play9112.com");

print qq|Doing $domain \n|;

$p->ping($domain,5);`

Comment: @AndrewNewby Have you tried it without `use Time::Out`?

Comment: @ceving yup. Can you repeat the same issue your end? I wonder if its server related? Still odd that the same codes works for millions of other domains - but just gets caught up on a few.

Comment: @HellmarBecker I'm wondering if I may be better just to move over to this, which works: `timeout 5s ping -c 1 -W 1 $domain`. Is there a way to simply get true/false for a ping though? Currently it spits out the first response

Comment: please check this https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/cook/ch18_08.htm  ... # use TCP if we're not root, ICMP if we are `$pong = Net::Ping->new( $> ? "tcp" : "icmp" );`

Comment: Please check https://perldoc.perl.org/Net::Ping ... If a timeout in seconds is provided, it is used when a timeout is not given to the ping() method (below). The timeout must be greater than 0 and the default, if not specified, is 5 seconds. If the hostname cannot be found or there is a problem with the IP number, the success flag returned will be undef. Otherwise, the success flag will be 1 if the host is reachable and 0 if it is not.

Comment: @amitbhosale thanks. It looks I was using new() wrong (I was passing timeout to `ping()`. Anyway, that still didn't fix it. I did just test the same code on one of my other servers - and it works! The problem server is v5.26.1 , and the newer one is v5.30.0. I wonder if thats the issue. I do actually need to rebuild this server, but its quite a job as there is a lot on it :(

Comment: Please check this scenario also ..'if you use a name instead of an IP address, the resolution of the name does not count into these timeouts & waits (pinging and time measurements start only after the name resolution has finished). If you use DNS, you can set DNS timeouts in /etc/resolv.con'.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359487/why-does-ping-not-timeout-in-linux

Comment: @amitbhosale interestingly, that seems to have sorted it! I added in the timeout into resolve.conf (I had to create a new file, as the resolve.conf was linked to a system file, which gets overwritten each reboot - but nothing I've not done before on other servers :))

Comment: In CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7, or Ubuntu etc .. any custom DNS entries are stored in the file /etc/resolv.conf. However, if we simply go ahead and add our nameservers to this file, we’ll notice that after a reboot or a restart of the network.service, the file is overwritten by NetworkManager.  check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-when-resolv-conf-is-being-overwritten

Comment: @amitbhosale actually, on Ubuntu 18.04, its a symlink to  `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. Renaming the symlink and making your own resolv.conf file works :)